# How to let div grow with content while not lay over other content

Tags: html, css, layout, tabs

I have a code for html/css tabbing. Unfortunately, it's scrolling for too long content. Since I don't know in advance, how long my texts will be, I want the text div to grow with the content.

I think the problem should be the position: absolute; but when I change this to relative (even just the div, not the input), the tabs are broken and the whole text div lays over other content of the page.

My full example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/0f8hno5o/

Here some parts:

```
<div class="tabreiter">
   <ul>
       <li>
           <input type="radio" name="tabreiter-0" checked="checked" id="tabreiter-0-0" /><label for="tabreiter-0-0">Tab 1</label>
            <div>
                 Long Text ...
            </div>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Part of my CSS:

```
.tabreiter
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
}   

.tabreiter ul,
.tabreiter li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.tabreiter,
.tabreiter input[type="radio"]:checked + label
{
    position: relative;
}

.tabreiter li,
.tabreiter input[type="radio"] + label
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.tabreiter li > div ,
.tabreiter input[type="radio"]
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: This might be a helpful source to see how it can be solved: http://codepen.io/JamieKDonnelly/pen/wBQQPK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible with only html/css so I'm thinking you'll need some javascript/jquery. (i'm going to write a small snippet of jQuery, but if you don't use that you'll have to rewrite it to plain javascript)

I'd hook it on the change event of the radio buttons, since your tabs work with those.
Also, you will have to change the code of the tabs just a little bit, because otherwise I think jquery can't work out the height of the contents.

```
<div class="tabreiter">
   <ul>
       <li>
           <input type="radio" name="tabreiter-0" checked="checked" id="tabreiter-0-0" /><label for="tabreiter-0-0">Tab 1</label>
            <div>
                <div> <!-- added extra div which will have the height we need -->
                     Long Text ...
                </div>
            </div>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the jQuery:

```
<script>
//being extra specific here because I don't know if you've got other radio buttons on the page somewhere
$('.tabreiter ul li input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {

    //calculate height of contents:
    // you'll need to add the height of the tabs + the margins /top offsets set by your css, I haven't checked them precisely so these are rough estimates
    var newHeight = $(this).parent('li').find('div>div').height() + 34 + 16 + 38;

    set the height of the container div to match the newly calculated height
    $('.tabreiter').height(newHeight);

});

//this triggers the change function to set correct height on page load
$('.tabreiter ul li input[type=radio]:checked').change();
</script>
```